# How to perform foreach in an array

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I use smarty on a prestashop template.

this is the code I use

```
{Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product)}
```

It give me an array... with array inside. this is an exemple :

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [id_category] => 2
        [name] => Accueil
        [link_rewrite] => home
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id_category] => 7
        [name] => Dancefloor
        [link_rewrite] => dancefloor
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [id_category] => 12
        [name] => other
        [link_rewrite] => other
    )

)
```

I would like to find a way to get all the "link_rewrite" element : home,dancefloor,other.

It's possible with php, but the script is on a .tpl file. So How can I do this with smarty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
{assign var=items value=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product)}

{foreach $items as $v}
  {$v["link_rewrite"]}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: it's ok if you put `{$v["link_rewrite"]}` instead of `{$v["[link_rewrite]"]}`. thks

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong. I understand that you want to show Category link , this is the best solution. I have tested my self the code in my local prestashop site

```
{assign var=items value=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product)}


{foreach $items as $v}
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($v['id_category'], $v['link_rewrite'])|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"> {$v['name']}</a>

{/foreach}
```

Comment: In fact i need to concatenate the value.                            `{assign var=out value=""}  
    {assign var=items value=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product)}
      {foreach $items as $v}
    {assign var=out value=$out|cat:" "|cat:$v["link_rewrite"] }
    {/foreach}`